# Unknown intent found, while trying to train model using rest api

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I was trying to make a panel through which the user can train the model using rest API. But while using the API given for train the model I got the issue “Found unknown Intent”. Below is the code what I have tried

```
const json2md = require("json2md");

fs.writeFileSync('./domain.yml', params.domain2)
fs.writeFileSync('./responses.yml', params.responses2)
fs.writeFileSync('./nlu.md', json2md(params.nlu.data));
fs.writeFileSync('./stories.md', json2md(params.stories.data));

let req_domain = await processLineByLine('domain.yml');
let req_response = await processLineByLine('responses.yml');
let req_nlu = await processLineByLine('nlu.md');
let req_stories = await processLineByLine('stories.md');
let req_config = await processLineByLine(path.join(__dirname,'../../../../', 'public/apiDocsV1', 'config.yml'));

async function processLineByLine(fileName) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
      crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  let arr = [];
  for await (const line of rl) {
      arr.push(line + '\n');
  }
  return arr.join('')
```

}

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:5002/model/train', {
    domain: req_domain,
    config: req_config,
    nlu: req_nlu,
    responses: req_response,
    stories: req_stories,
    force: false,
    save_to_default_model_directory: true
});
```

And here is the screenshot from the rasa endpoint
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfG6g.png)

The files look good and even the domain file is also good but unable to create and train the model. Please help

Comment: If you look at the end of the error, it looks like a valid domain file was not found, which means your domain probably did not get loaded in correctly. Do you have a printout of what `req_domain` contains? Maybe it is not rendered correctly. Are you able to train your model locally with that domain file?

Answer (score 0):

The `domain.yml` file seems to be not formatted correctly. Use the site https://www.yamllint.com for checking whether the YML formatting is correct or not.I can see the error *Invalid domain file* from the screenshot.